# getting error in activation of theme in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I have install a new theme in wordpress after uploading but at the time of activation of the theme , getting the error like this:

Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\realhomes\framework\meta-box\inspiry-meta-box.php on line 11

Please help me through this:
add_action('admin_init',function(){ :  is line 11 in my code.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {

include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

// Meta Box Plugin
if ( is_plugin_active( 'meta-box/meta-box.php' ) ) {
    deactivate_plugins( 'meta-box/meta-box.php' );
    add_action( 'admin_notices', function () {
        ?>
        <div class="update-nag notice is-dismissible">
            <p><strong><?php _e( 'Meta Box plugin has been deactivated!', 'framework' ); ?></strong></p>
            <p><?php _e( 'As now its functionality is embedded with in Real Homes theme.', 'framework' ); ?></p>
            <p><em><?php _e( 'So, You should completely remove it from your plugins.', 'framework' ); ?></em></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your brackets not over in your last line of code..
please add this in last line  });